# InsertRow and automatic render in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i have a JTable and a custom table model , wich has in some places `Double.class` as column class. I read from a database and then insert result  to the table. I want the numbers to be rendered  with 2 decimals so i use this class

```
    public class NumberCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

@Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (c instanceof JLabel && value instanceof Number) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
                Number num = (Number) value;
                String text = numberFormat.format(num);
                label.setText(text);

            }
            return c;
```

}
    }

The problem is when i call addRow, the Double.class columns didn't format

```
  public void addRowData( IEntity entity ) {
        getRowsData().add(entity);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

The question is when i call this i have to call something more to render the table??

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do they ever format correctly?

Comment: Did you add the renderer to the table? Did you override the getColumnClass() method of the TAbleModel.

Comment: @camickr No is no overrided, should be? , i didnt do it :S they just gave me this deadly thing :P, i think could be that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example to override the getColumnClass() method:

```
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
```

Then to add the renderer to the table you do:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, new NumberCellRenderer());
```

You might also want to check out [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for some generic renderers and you could use:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, new NumberRenderer( new DecimalFormat("#.00") ));
```